# How to get AccessToken or Session string in WinUI 3 application to initiate set up of AWS Cognito MFA

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, winui-3

I am building WinUI 3 desktop app which uses AWS Cognito for user sign-up/sign-in and I came across a problem when trying to implement MFA set up after user creation.

According to AWS documentation I need to call `AssociateSoftwareToken` with `AssociateSoftwareTokenRequest` parameter and its "Access Token" or "Session String" properties set to authorize the request:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/MCognitoIdentityProviderAssociateSoftwareTokenAsyncAssociateSoftwareTokenRequestCancellationToken.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/TAssociateSoftwareTokenRequest.html

My question is - how can I get the AccessToken or Session string from my preceding sign-in request to then authorize `AssociateSoftwareToken` in WinUi 3 desktop app?

I've googled around and read AWS and MS docs but cannot find anything helpful in this regard.

My code snippets:

1. User sign-in method:

```
        try
        {
            AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), FallbackRegionFactory.GetRegionEndpoint())
            CognitoUserPool cognitoUserPool = new(poolID, clientID, provider);
            CognitoUser cognitoUser = new(username, clientID, cognitoUserPool, provider);
            InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new()
            {
                Password = password
            };
            AuthFlowResponse authFlowResponse = await cognitoUser.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (authFlowResponse.AuthenticationResult is null)
            {  
                if (authFlowResponse.ChallengeName == ChallengeNameType.MFA_SETUP)
                {
                   //At this point I need AccessToken or Session string to to call CognitoSetUpTOTPMFAAsync(string accessToken) to trigger MFA setup...
                }
                .
                //remaining implementation
                .
            }
            return ...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ...
        }
```

2. CognitoSetUpTOTPMFAAsync(string accessToken OR string sessionString)

```
        try
        {
            
            AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), FallbackRegionFactory.GetRegionEndpoint());
            AssociateSoftwareTokenRequest associateSoftwareTokenRequest = new()
            {
                AccessToken = accessToken,
                Session = sessionString               
            };
            AssociateSoftwareTokenResponse associateSoftwareTokenResponse = await provider.AssociateSoftwareTokenAsync(associateSoftwareTokenRequest);
            .
            //remaining implementation
            .
            return ...
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the required "Session string" is returned after initial sign in request in **AuthFlowResponse** object as **SessionID** parameter. It is contained in each response from Cognito and can be used to supply with consecutive requests.

Adding this to my code:

```
...
AuthFlowResponse authFlowResponse = await cognitoUser.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest);
var sessionId = authFlowResponse.SessionID;
...
```

Then provide `sessionId` to MFA setup `AssociateSoftwareTokenRequest` request:

```
...
AssociateSoftwareTokenRequest associateSoftwareTokenRequest = new()
   {
   Session = sessionId                
   };
AssociateSoftwareTokenResponse associateSoftwareTokenResponse = await provider.AssociateSoftwareTokenAsync(associateSoftwareTokenRequest);
...
```

Then `associateSoftwareTokenResponse` contains `SecretCode` value to be used to register with authenticator app.